# Getting MSISDN from mobile browser headers

Tags: browser, mobile, http-headers, mobile-website, mobile-phones

What is the best way of going about this? I need to get MSISDN data from users accessing a mobisite to enhance the user experience.
I understand not all gateways would populate the headers entirely, but would wish to have MSISDN capture as option one before falling back on a cookie based model

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I'd like to give my contribution.

I work for a mobile carrier and here we have a feature that you can set some parameteres for header enrichment. We create some filters to match certain traffic passing through the GGSN (GPRS gateway node) then it opens the packages at layer 7 (when application layer is HTTP - not protected with SSL) and write msisdn, imsi and other parameters inside it.

So it is a carrier-depending feature.

Comment: I think this kind of question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
Since you are an expert in Telco, if you like the proposal, follow-it so that it can be launched

Answer (score 3):

While some operators do this, the representation and mechanism depends entirely on the operator.  There is no standard way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay for it try http://Bango.com. They provide an api but you may need to redirect user to their service

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there is no standard way between mobile operators for passing the MSISDN in the HTTP headers.

Different operators vary on the header value used, some operators do not pass the MSISDN unless they "authorize" your website and others have more complicated means of passing the MSISDN (e.g. redirects to their network to pick up the header).

Developing a site for one specific operator is easy enough, developing for multiple is next to impossible if you need to rely on the header.